# Java Web Service and XML

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I am sort of new in java programming (less than 2 months) and can you guys please give me some advice of how to achieve this scenario? What and which areas I need to look at and read to understand.

**Things I have done so far is :**

Created a new web server and web application project on netbeans, deployed and tested no problem, created a XSD schema file and created JAXB Binding with a XML file.

**Create a cinema booking service**

1) XML file based on an XSD schema.

2) The web service should be able to return values when booking has been made. (I am struggling to understand what requires in here to create the return process. But I do know that using JAXB, I can unmarshall the XML file and convert it to Java and show it to the user. However I do not understand how I can marshall an input from an interface and update the XML file.)

3) implement a search functionality allow my users to search the availability of cinema tickets and have the option to search with specific criteria such as what film, genre, age.

Comment: Voting up really makes this answer use ful for every one  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to java and web service and learn JSP/Servlets first learn some thing about Java methods and java interfaces.

If you want to use XML and XSD for web service just try this tutorial

[JAXB](http://javapapers.com/jee/jaxb-tutorial/)

[Web service](http://javapapers.com/web-service/web-service-introduction-tutorial/)

[STAX](http://javapapers.com/jee/java-stax/)

To create a Soap web service

[SOAP example](http://javapapers.com/web-service/soap-web-service-introduction/)